# How to take specific words in the text and append it by using python?

Tags: python, append, readline

I am now trying to convert input file into output file by using python.

And I have input file as below: (the 'random_text' are contents that are no needs to be considered)

```
random_text

reg A1_M0;
reg A1_M1;
reg A1_M10;
reg A1_M11;
reg A1_M2;

reg [3:0] B1_M0;
reg [3:0] B1_M1;
reg [3:0] B1_M10;
reg [3:0] B1_M11;
reg [3:0] B1_M2;

random_text

Test("C1_upper")
random_text
Test("C1_lower[3]")
random_text
:
Test("C1_lower[0]")
random_text
Test("C2_upper")
random_text
Test("C2_lower[3]")
random_text
:
Test("C2_lower[0]")
random_text
:
:
Test("C5_upper")
random_text
Test("C5_lower[3]")
random_text
:
Test("C5_lower[0]")
random_text
```

What I want to do is to put the text inside the certain line of input like this:(highlighted in ** mark)

```
random_text

reg A1_M0;
reg A1_M1;
reg A1_M10;
reg A1_M11;
reg A1_M2;

reg [3:0] B1_M0;
reg [3:0] B1_M1;
reg [3:0] B1_M10;
reg [3:0] B1_M11;
reg [3:0] B1_M2;

random_text

Test("C1_upper")
**A1_M0 = C**
random_text
Test("C1_lower[3]")
**B1_M0[3] = C** 
random_text
:
Test("C1_lower[0]")
**B1_M0[0] = C** 
random_text
Test("C2_upper")
**A1_M1 = C**
random_text
Test("C2_lower[3]")
**B1_M1[3] = C**
random_text
:
Test("C2_lower[0]")
**B1_M1[0] = C**
random_text
:
:
Test("C5_upper")
**A1_M2 = C**
random_text
Test("C5_lower[3]")
**B1_M2[3] = C**
random_text
:
Test("C5_lower[0]")
**B1_M2[0] = C**
random_text
```

So, In conclusion, A1_M0~M2 matches C1~C5_upper each, and B1_M0[3]~[0] matches C1_lower[3]~[0], B1_M1[3]~[0] matches C2_lower[3]~[0], B1_M10[3]~[0] matches C3_lower[3]~[0] so on so forth.

Namely, M0->C1, M1->C2, M10->C3, M11->C4, M2->C5

It seems like I need to set 2 steps.

1. list up the specific lines ('reg' lines) and reset(by using split) the list like : [0, 1, 10, 11, 2]
2. find 'Test' part and append from the list data.

And, When I tried to use .readlines(), Seemed like I skipped some steps.
Is there any simple way to deal with this?

Thank you.